# gradient on path:hover when path is transitioned

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am pretty much new to d3 and i'm working on a d3 project with a friend for a couple of weeks now.

We built a website containing a sankey diagram and a filter that influences the thickness of links and nodes. Therefore the filter has `updateSankey()` as an event Handler for the change event.
The links are black with `stroke-opacity: 0.15`

Lately we tried to introduce a feature that appends a linear gradient to a path `onmouseover` and removes it `onmouseout`
To make this work we added an eventHandler to each path which calls a function on both the events. in the functions we append or remove the linear gradient. The gradient goes from the color of the source-node to the color of the target-node.

The problem: after filtering, when all the links have been transitioned the source-node and target-node inside the eventhandler isn't updated and therefore the gradient has wrong colors.

[this is how it should look like, it works properly if i don't change the filter on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVnMp.png)

[as soon as i change the filter on the left, the colors get messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16jSD.png)

I think we have to do a transition to update these colors, but i have absolutely no idea how and where i have to do this, so i would be glad if you guys could help me.

Down below you find all relevant functions as they currently are.

Greetings and thanks alot in advance
bäsi

```js
/**
 * Initialize Sankey
 */
function initSankey() {
    /*simple initialisation of the sankey, should explain itself*/

    svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width") - 2*marginleft,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margintop;

    formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
        format = function (d) { return formatNumber(d) + " %"; },
        color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    sankey = d3.sankey()
        .nodeWidth(15)
        .nodePadding(10)
        .extent([[1, 1], [width - 1, height - 6]])
        .iterations(0);

    t = d3.transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear);

    //set attributes for all links
    titleGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "titles")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "150%");

    diagram= svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "sankey")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginleft + "," + margintop + ")");

    linkGroup = diagram.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .attr("fill", "none");
        //.attr("stroke", "#000")
        //.attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2);

    //set attributes for all nodes
    nodeGroup = diagram.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", 10);
}

/**
 * for the filtering and transition by selecting a filter we need to update the sankey and "draw" it new
 * */
function updateSankey() {
    flush();
    filter();
    calculateLinks();
    switch (lang)
    {
        case "ger":
            d3.json("data/labels-ger.json", helper);
            break;
        case "fra":
            d3.json("data/labels-fr.json", helper);
            break;
        case "eng":
            d3.json("data/labels-en.json", helper);
            break;
        default:
            d3.json("data/labels.json", helper);
    }
}

/**
 *  the main function for "drawing" the saneky, takes the customLinks that where calculated and returns the saneky
 * */
function helper(error, labels) {
    if (error)
        throw error;
    labels.links = customLinks;
    sankey(labels);
    var links = linkGroup.selectAll('path')
        .data(labels.links);

    //Set attributes for each link separately
    links.enter().append("g")
        .attr("id",function (d,i) {return "path"+i;})
        .attr("from",function (d) { return d.source.name; })
        .attr("to",function (d) { return d.target.name; })
        .append("path")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.15)
        .attr("display", function (d) {
            /* don't display a link if the link is smaller than 4%, else it will be just displayed*/
            if(d.value < 4.0){return "none";}
            else{return "inline";}
        })
        .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
        .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {return Math.max(1, d.width); })
        .on("mouseover",function (d,id) {
            var pathGroup = svg.select('#path' + id);
            var path = pathGroup.select("path");

            /*var from = document.getElementById("path" + id).__data__.source;
            var to = document.getElementById("path" + id).__data__.target;
            console.log(from)
            console.log(to)
            */

            var pathGradient = pathGroup.append("defs")
                .append("linearGradient")
                .attr("id","grad" + id)
                .attr("gradientUnit","userSpaceOnUse")
                .attr("style","mix-blend-mode: multiply;")
                .attr("x1","0%")
                .attr("x2","100%")
                .attr("y1","0%")
                .attr("y2","0%");

            pathGradient.append("stop")
                .attr("class","from")
                .attr("offset","0%")
                .attr("style", function (d) {
                    var color = setColor(d.source);
                    return "stop-color:" + color + ";stop-opacity:1";
                });

            pathGradient.append("stop")
                .attr("class","to")
                .attr("offset","100%")
                .attr("style",function (d) {
                    var color = setColor(d.target);
                    return "stop-color:" + color + ";stop-opacity:1";
                });

            path.attr("stroke","url(#grad"+id+")")
                .attr("stroke-opacity","0.95");
        })
        //.attr("onmouseover",function (d,i) { return "appendGradient(" + i + ")" })
        .on("mouseout",function (d, id) {
            pathGroup = svg.select('#path' + id);
            var path = pathGroup.select("path");

            var pathGradient = pathGroup.select("defs")
                .remove();

            path.attr("stroke","#000")
                .attr("stroke-opacity","0.15");
        })
        //.attr("onmouseout",function (d,i) { return "removeGradient(" + i + ")" })
        .append("title")
        .text(function (d) {
            //tooltip info for the links
            return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

    linkGroup.selectAll("g").transition(t)
        .attr("id",function (d,i) {return "path"+i;})
        .attr("from",function (d) { return d.source.name; })
        .attr("to",function (d) { return d.target.name; });

    links.transition(t)
        .attr("display", function (d) {
            //again if the link is smaller than 4% don't display it, we have to do this method again because of the
            // transition, if another filter is selected
            if(d.value < 4.0){return "none";}
            else{return "inline";}
        })
        .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
        .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.max(1, d.width); })
        .select('title')
        .text(function (d) {
            //same argumentation as above, we need the method again for the transition
            return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

    //remove the unneeded links
    links.exit().remove();

    var nodes = nodeGroup.selectAll('.node')
        .data(labels.nodes);

    var nodesEnter = nodes.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr('class', 'node');

    //set attributes for each node separately
    nodesEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x0; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y0; })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            var width = d.x1 - d.x0;
            if(d.value > 0)
            {
                //this is used for the years above the nodes, every x position of all nodes is pushed in an array
                columnCoord.push(d.x0 + width/2);
            }
            return width;
        })
        .attr("fill", setColor)
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)

    //specify Pop-Up when hovering over node
    nodesEnter.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

    //Update selection
    var nodesUpdate = nodes.transition(t);

    //same as the links we have to state the methods again in the update
    nodesUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y0; })
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x0; })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; });

    nodesUpdate.select("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

    //Exit selection
    nodes.exit().remove();

    //we filter all arrays
    columnCoord = filterArray(columnCoord);
    if(!titlesDrawn)
    {
        drawTitles();
        titlesDrawn = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a working [mcve] so readers can see the problem in action without having to do a lot of work.  You are more likely to get answers that way.

Comment: hi paul, since there are multiple files including jsons it's quite hard to create a minimal version, instead i added two screens in the hope of clarifying what i mean.